# Setting array value to greater than 1

Tags: php, arrays, operators

I have the array, $gush. The variable 'you_pick' has potential values from 0-10. I am passing the array $gush to my model to get records from my db that match $gush. I want to return all the records where the variable 'you_pick' = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10. I don't want the results where the variable 'you_pick' = 0. Right now, I have set 'you_pick' equal to 1. How do I set 'you_pick' in the array to be greater than 0? Or, conversely, to not equal 0?

```
    $data = array(
        'order' => 'RAND()',
        'offset' => ($pp * $page) - $pp,
        'limit' => $pp
    );

    $return = array();


    $gush = array(
        'for_dog' => 1,
        'active' => 1,
        'you_pick' => array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10')
    );


    $collars =  Collars_Model_Collar::findBy($gush, $data);
```

Here is the model:

```
public static function findBy(array $data = null, array $params = null, $_callbackQuery = null)
{
    $_callbackQuery = $_callbackQuery ? $_callbackQuery : array('Collars_Model_Collar', 'extendResult');
    if (isset($params['order']) && stripos($params['order'], 'collar.price ') !== false) {
        $p = explode(' ', $params['order']);
        $params['order'] = new JO_Db_Expr('( collar.price/(SELECT `value` FROM `currency` WHERE `code`=shop_currency LIMIT 1) ) ' . $p[1]);
    }
    $collars = parent::findBy($data, $params, $_callbackQuery);
    $collars = self::addExtraProperties($collars);
    return $collars;
}
```

Here is more model stuff:

```
public static function findByPicks(array $data = null, array $params = null, $_callbackQuery = null)
{
    $_callbackQuery = $_callbackQuery ? $_callbackQuery : array('Collars_Model_Collar', 'extendResult');
    $collars = parent::findBy($data, $params, $_callbackQuery);
    $collars = self::addExtraProperties($collars);
    return $collars;
}


public static function extendResult($data) {

    if ($data instanceof JO_Db_Select) {
        $db = JO_Db::getDefaultAdapter();


//  a bunch of stuff

        $data->columns($rows);


//  a bunch of stuff

        $data->where('collar.active IN (0, 1, 2, 3)');

//  a bunch of stuff

        $clone = clone $data;
        $clone->reset(JO_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
                ->reset(JO_Db_Select::ORDER)
                ->reset(JO_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT)
                ->reset(JO_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)
                ->limit(1);

        self::$total = $db->fetchOne('SELECT COUNT(' . self::$_table . '.' . self::$_primaryKey . ') ' . $clone);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to clear up what you're asking.  `$gush['you_pick']` is already greater than 0.

Comment: Tx @Devon. I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Are you asking about searching for a number that is greater than 0?  That really isn't how conditionals work in PHP.  It is possible your Model logic accepts something that allows it to query the database, but we can't answer that for you without much more code or context.

Comment: What you ask does not really make sense. A variable (or an array element in this case) has to have a specific value. Not something vague like "greater than zero". That would be a comparison term, so much more complex. If such thing can be expressed completely depends on your environment, so controller and model, which you did not share with us. Specifically it depends on _how_ the model evaluates that argument you hand over. We cannot _guess_ that, you have to tell us.

Comment: @Devon: Sorry, still learning how to ask the best questions.  I am passing the array $gush to my model to get records from my db that match $gush. I want to return all the records where the variable 'you_pick' = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or  10. I don't want the records where the variable 'you_pick' = 0.  Is that clearer? Maybe this can't be done in an array as such?

Comment: Tx @arkascha, That makes sense. I have updated my question. Is it possible to set an array element so that it does not equal something?  In this case, I don't want results where you_pick = 0.

Comment: @ian No, that can't be done by setting an array value.  A variable cannot be equal to a condition like arkascha said.

Comment: As said before: it depends on _how_ that array is evaluated. You still did not tell us...

Comment: @Devon. Tx for the reply. Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I want - e.g. can i define a variable to the condition I want and then set you_pick equal to that variable in the array?

Comment: Tx @arkascha, added the function from the model as well as the $data variable that also gets passed.

Comment: No, you did _not_ post the method actually evaluating said array. The array is only passed on by the method you posted: `parent::findBy($data, $params, $_callbackQuery);`.

Comment: @arkascha The problem is that the model is hundreds of lines of code so I am trying to provide the basics for you to look at. Not sure if you can get anything further from what I just added? In fact, you_pick does not appear anywhere in the model.

Comment: I am afraid we cannot somehow magically guess how your code works. Sorry.

Comment: @arkascha Not a problem. Really appreciate the input you provided to this point. I'll have to comb through the model line by line and try to figure it out. Tx again.

Comment: I see what the problem is with framing the question.  The gentleman lacks a clear understanding of what problem he is required to solve, whereas the MECHANICS of the solution (model/view/controller and such) have forcibly been thrust upon him with crystal clarity.  Why worry about the GOALS when you can focus on the MEANS?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help  I resolved the problem by nesting an array inside $gush. So: 'you_pick' =>  array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10').

Answer (score 0):

nested an array by replacing
    'you_pick' => 1
with
    'you_pick' => array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10')